# Call the managed bean method using jquery ajax and get back the result in jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf-2

Call the managed bean method using jquery ajax and get back the result in jquery. I have searched about it and got he url to call but can i call directly the back bean method from jquery ajax and how?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly call a managed bean from javascript with standard JSF2. It doesn't fit into the normal life cycle and component model of the JSF.

You could use CDI and the Seam Remoting module to do this though. http://seamframework.org/Seam3/RemotingModule It exposes CDI beans, which JSF2 can access just like managed beans, as endpoints that you can call from your javascript code.